# Shibboleth login issue

Tags: nginx, single-sign-on, shibboleth, dspace

I have set the Shibboleth Identity Provider at `server A` with domain name `idp.XXX.gr`.

Then I set a proxy with an embedded service provider at `server B` with domain name `proxy.XXX.gr`.

`proxy.XXX.gr` and `idp.XXX.gr` works great together. The problem starts when I try to connect the second application to the SSO system.

The second application is a `Dspace` and it is install at the `server C` and at the same server I set a Shibboleth Service Provider with domain name `sp-dspace.XXX.gr`.

Service Provider `sp-dspace.XXX.gr` works great with Identity Provider `idp.XXX.gr`.

In front of Dspace there is a nginx at `server D` with a domain name `dspace.XXX.gr`, which redirects to the Dspace application.

When I try to login to Dspace with Shibboleth login, I go to `sp-dspace.XXX.gr` (by redirection) and then to the `idp.XXX.gr` login page. There, I submit my credentials and the login is successfully, but instead of redirecting back to `sp-dspace.XXX.gr` and then to `dspace.XXX.gr` I get an idp error page with the following message:

```
Error Message: No peer endpoint available to which to send SAML response
```

If then I tried to login to `proxy.XXX.gr`, I do not have to put my credentials because I am already logged in.

This is my problem scenario. My thoughts are rather I have missed to configure a setting to redirect back, or maybe I am missing something (eg `dspace.XXX.gr` and `sp-dspace.XXX.gr` must have the same domain name or `dspace.XXX.gr` must have the same global ip with `sp-dspace.XXX.gr`).

Comment: Every google result for "Error Message: No peer endpoint available to which to send SAML response" ends up being a config error. You have posted no config.

Comment: In particular, can you post the nginx config for dspace.XXX.gr? And also can you clarify, do you really mean that you 'redirect' rather than just forward the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the same domain name for Service Provider (SP) and Dpace. After that, you should use apache httpd you installed for your SP, in front of your dspace tomcat (VirtualHost / ssl.conf ) following the [Dspace 4 documentation](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/Authentication+Plugins#AuthenticationPlugins-ShibbolethAuthentication).